# How to check all checkbox on checking one checkbox in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have created 5 checkboxes dynamically through for loop

```
<v-checkbox 
    v-model="selectAll"
    label="Select All"
    @change="select_All($event)"
></v-checkbox>

<template v-for="n in 5">
    <v-checkbox 
       v-model="selected[n]"
    ></v-checkbox>
</template>
```

In script

```
data(){
    return{
        selected:[],
                selectAll: false
    }
},
methods:{
    select_All(e){
        if(e == true)
        {
            // check all the checkbox
        } else {
            // uncheck all the checkbox
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I have created checkboxes dynamically,(if you have any better suggestion for how to create dynamic checkbox please tell me)
Now I have a checkbox above all and if I click(check) on that checkbox all the below checkbox should be selected or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the selected array to make all the indexes to true But in the very first time, you have to get the length of checkboxes from some other source instead of selected array.(I'm using refs to count checkboxes here)

the code would be something like below

```
<v-checkbox 
  ref="n"
  v-model="selected[n]"
></v-checkbox>


select_All(e){
        if(e == true)
        {
          this.$refs.n.forEach((val, index) => this.selected[index] = true)
        } else {
            this.$refs.n.forEach((val, index) => this.selected[index] = false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I am getting error [ 'forEach' of undefined ]. If I do console the  console.log(this.$refs.n) this gives undefined.

Comment: oops my bad, you don't need to put colon infront of ref="n", edited.

Comment: Thanks, it works. This is exactly what I wanted. I have one more thing to ask if you can help, like how we can pass ref value from one component to another?

Comment: Thats great :), to pass any value to other component, you can define a prop in the other component and pass the value in that prop. e.g. <other-comp :countFromRefs="$refs.n.length" /> something like this

Comment: yes this is how we pass values from parent to child component but what if I want to pass the ref  value from child to parent component?

Comment: ah from child to parent, you need to pass a method from parent to child and child will emit that method with the refs data. about emitting you can follow this article https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: $emit('changeHeader', $refs) OR $emit('changeHeader', $refs.n) depends on your requirement

Comment: thanks, this works. You seems to be an expert in frontend, would you dont mind if I ask you something related to vuejs in future ?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the compliment. Yes, sure I'd happy to help if I could :)

Comment: hello brother, can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800048/how-to-enable-dark-mode-with-custom-colors-in-light-theme-in-vuetify

Comment: @shashiverma Answered :)

Comment: hello brother con you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092562/how-to-add-copy-to-clipboard-functionality-in-vuejs-with-prismjs

Comment: Hi @shashiverma, nice question, replied there.

Comment: hi bro, can you help me with this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211431/unhandled-promise-rejection-syntaxerror-expected-getting-this-on-ie11-with?noredirect=1#comment104639332_59211431

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of using `computed` for this case:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: [],
    count: 5
  },
  computed: {
    selectedAll: {
      set(val) {
        this.selected = []
        if (val) {
          for(let i = 1; i <= this.count; i++) {
            this.selected.push(i)
          }
        }
      },
      get() {
        return this.selected.length === this.count
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedAll" />
   Select all
 </label>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in count">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="n" />
        C {{ n }}
      </label> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But I haven't tested it by vuetify.

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this for select/deselect multiple dynamically generated checkboxes:

```
    <v-checkbox v-model="selected" @click.native.stop="selectAll()" />
    <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox[0]" class="checkbox" @click.native.stop />
    <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox[1]" class="checkbox" @click.native.stop />
    <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox[2]" class="checkbox" @click.native.stop />
    <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox[3]" class="checkbox" @click.native.stop />
    <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox[4]" class="checkbox" @click.native.stop />
```

Checkboxes above can be dynamically generated. I use (not this case) v-for cycle code block with API id's as index.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkbox: {},
    selected: false
  },
  mounted () {
    /* this is just example, in this case you could type number properties 
    directly in data.checkbox like checkbox[0] = false etc., but in a real case 
    you may want to use string ID or any API based index with it's corresponding 
    v-for html markdown */
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      // maintaining reactivity
      this.$set(this.checkbox, i, false)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectAll () {
      for (const i in this.checkbox) {
        this.checkbox[i] = this.selected
      }
    }
  }

})
```

You can probably replace `mounted` block for this if you want:

```
watch: {
  checkbox: {
    immediate: true,
    handler () {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // maintaining reactivity
        this.$set(this.checkbox, i, false)
      }
    }
  }
}
```