# How to enable dark mode with custom colors in light theme in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify 2.0 and I am facing an issue, in my vuetify.js file I have the following code

```
export default new Vuetify({
    theme:{
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: '#3f51b5',
                secondary: '#b0bec5',
                accent: '#8c9eff',
                error: '#b71c1c',
              }
        },
        dark: true
    }

})
```

vuetify theme https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme

Here, I have set the custom color for the light theme by default but when I set the dark to true the colors I have set for light gets changed. Why this is happening, why can't I have my own color on dark mode? How can we override this or this is a default feature?

Updated below

```
export default new Vuetify({
    theme:{
        themes: {
            light: store.getters.selectedTheme.theme,
            dark: store.getters.selectedTheme.theme
        },
        // dark: true
    },

})
```

and true/false for dark is I am setting through checkbox and the method I am calling on onChange on checkbox is below

```
emitDarkMode(e) {
        this.$vuetify.theme.dark = e;
      // this.$store.dispatch("darkModeHandler");
    },
```

The main thing is, I have 5 differnt color sets for theme like for primary, secondary etc and setting these theme colot with radio button.
Like If I click on red(error), theme color will be set to red and so on. and doing all this with vuex.
But when I switch to dark mode my theme color gets change to the default color of vuetify and I am unable to dynamically change the theme color through radio button on dark mode.

Thanks

Comment: where is dark theme defined?

Comment: I mean the colors for dark theme?

Comment: I have a customizer sidebar component there I have a checkbox for dark mode funcionality

Comment: what does this line returns? store.getters.selectedTheme.theme....

I think in case of Dark theme, it return no color, but you will need to define dark theme as well

Comment: Thanks bro for your response, I have solved the problem.  You spare time for my question and helped me once again. Thank you so much

Comment: Pleasure is all mine bro

Comment: yes you are right it was returning no color I had this in my code **this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light = theme.theme;** for themes then I added this line for dark **this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark = theme.theme;** and that works. Actually I am beginer in vuejs and got a working project and I was updating its vuetify version thats why. But thanks once again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198997/discussion-between-asim-khan-and-shashi-verma).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

and you can define other dark theme like below

```
export default new Vuetify({
    theme:{
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: '#3f51b5',
                secondary: '#b0bec5',
                accent: '#8c9eff',
                error: '#b71c1c',
              },
            dark: {
              //here you will define primary secondary stuff for dark theme
            }
        },
        dark: true
    }

})
```

Comment: this one is working fine, but when I am getting these theme color through vuex then I am facing problem, let me update my question

Comment: When I define a theme, I don't see that the background color of elements changes. But When I change dark to false or from false to true I see that background colors also changes.It seems like setting only 6 colors does not change the style completely. How can I change style completely.

Answer (score 9):

I found this question while trying to figure out how to switch between light and dark themes **based on system preferences**. This [post](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7932#issuecomment-572942707) helped me.

```js
const mq = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')

export const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: { dark: mq.matches }
})

mq.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  vuetify.framework.theme.dark = e.matches
})
```

All credit goes to [jellehak](https://github.com/jellehak)

Answer (score 1):

so there can be two variants of themes as light and dark. by default light theme is applied but you can active dark theme by

```
dark: true
```

so I think you don't need to add this line here.

But if you also want to define dark theme then it will be useful later on.

now this code should work fine for you

```
  theme:{
    themes: {
        light: {
            primary: '#3f51b5',
            secondary: '#b0bec5',
            accent: '#8c9eff',
            error: '#b71c1c',
          }
        }
    }
```

updated answer:

what does this line return? `store.getters.selectedTheme.theme`

I think in case of Dark theme, it returns no color, but you will need to define dark theme as well