# How to add copy to clipboard functionality in vuejs with prismjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, clipboard.js, prismjs

I am displaying Html syntax using vue-prism-component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-prism-component).
Now I want to add a button that should copy the code. So far, I have found a library vue-clipboard2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clipboard2) in this they are getting text from an input tag. How I would select the syntax of Html generated by vue-prism-component on a click of button.

Answer (score 3):

Prism has some documentation for implementing such feature

https://prismjs.com/plugins/copy-to-clipboard/

Here is the example code for copying code from vue-prism-component

```
[Codepen] https://codepen.io/wilbo/pen/xRVLOj
```

You need to add this dependency of clipboard
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.12/clipboard.min.js

another codepen example which is not in vue but just to get idea

```
[Codepen] https://codepen.io/drhodes/pen/NAOgpG
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the codepen you provide is not what I want, in this they are selecting a single line and I have to select a block.Please open this link https://github.com/Inndy/vue-clipboard2/issues/73